# Export Access report as PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, pdf, oledbcommand

I'm doing an ASP.NET application in C# that connects to an Access database and now I want that it exports a report as PDF. Here is my code that only connects to Access, I was thinking of running an access macro or running a command with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application DoCmd.OutputTo but I do not know how to use it exactly. Any help?

```
string user = "myUser";
string pass = "myPass";
string host = "myHost";
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = myPath");
string _command = ...; //I don't know what put here

try
{
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(_command, connection);
    command.CommandText = ...; //I don't know what put here
    int temp = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("PDF created!");
 }
```

Comment: You're on the wrong path here. You can print reports to PDF, but you can't access reports using OleDb since that connects to the Access database (which handles tables, queries and data macro's, but not reports, forms, VBA and normal macros), and not the application.This: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317114/how-to-automate-microsoft-access-by-using-visual-c is a good starter on using COM and work with the Access application, and not the database. But try to get the print to PDF working in Access first, and then try to implement it in C#.

Comment: Why don't you use RDLC report? It provide inbuilt feature to export report as PDF or other format without preview it to user.

Comment: Thanks, I will search for automate Access but I don't know what is RDLC report and I don't know how to use it with Access.

Comment: Use article `https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492739/Exporting-to-Word-PDF-using-Microsoft-Report-RDLC` to get details for exporting report. RDLC is independent of database selection. You can provide the data externally to rdlc report using your datatable and it will work.

Answer (score 5):

I resolved my problem with the automation, I followed this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317114/how-to-automate-microsoft-access-by-using-visual-c (suggested me by Erik von Asmuth) and now I can export my report in PDF. My code now:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;

Application access = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
access.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"C:\Desktop\MyDB.accdb", false);

access.DoCmd.OutputTo(AcOutputObjectType.acOutputReport, 
    "Dati", //ReportName
    ".pdf", //OutputType
    @"C:\Desktop\Test.pdf",  //outupuFile
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
    AcExportQuality.acExportQualityPrint
);
```